# Keras word2vec model loss increasing

Tags: keras, word2vec, loss

I have built a Keras word2vec skipgram model similar to [this tutorial](http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/). Unfortunately, the loss keeps increasing from epoch to epoch and I cannot find the reason for it.

```
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Reshape, Activation, Input
from keras.layers.merge import Dot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

opt = rmsprop(lr=0.001)

embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size, input_length=1,
                      name='embedding')

w_inputs = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='float32')
w = embedding(w_inputs)
w = Reshape((emb_size, 1))(w)

c_inputs = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='float32')
c = embedding(c_inputs)
c = Reshape((emb_size, 1))(c)

o = Dot(axes=1)([w, c])
o = Reshape((1,), input_shape=(1, 1))(o)
o = Activation('sigmoid')(o)

model = Model(inputs=[w_inputs, c_inputs], outputs=o)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
```

Since the corpus consists of independent sentences, the training procedure is structured so that one sentence after another is used for training:

```
sampling_table = sequence.make_sampling_table(vocab_size)
epochs = 200
count = 0    

for i in range(epochs):
    loss = 0.
    for j, doc in enumerate(mapping):
        count += 1
        data, labels = skipgrams(sequence=doc,
                                 vocabulary_size=vocab_size,
                                 window_size=5,
                                 sampling_table=sampling_table)
        x = [np.array(x) for x in zip(*data)]
        y = np.array(labels, dtype=np.int32)
        if x:
            prev_loss = loss
            loss += sg.train_on_batch(x, y)

        if count % 10000 == 0:
            print(str(count)+' / '+str(len(mapping)))
```

The variable "mapping" is a list of lists (sentences) of word indices, encompassing ~370,000 sentences. Each sentence consists of minimum 2 words, however, the issue I am facing seems to be independent of the number of words in the sentence.